# Python not finishing for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I just started learning python and I figured for fun to see if I could make a python version of the monty hall problem. Everything seems to be working on a small scale when I use 1 or 2 iterations but past that nothing is working. The for loop is not finishing the amount of iterations I want it to.

```
import random

def problem(tests):

    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    doors = ["goat", "car", "goat"]

    for test in range(tests):
        #we shuffle the doors
        random.shuffle(doors)
        #the player picks a door
        choice = random.choice(doors)
        #monty chooses a door
        montychoice = random.choice(doors)
        while montychoice != 'car' or montychoice == choice:
            montychoice = random.choice(doors)

        #if the player's door is a car, he losses
        if choice == 'car':
            losses += 1
            print 'goat'
        elif choice == 'goat':
            wins += 1
            print 'car'

    print "Switching wins: %d" % wins
    print "Switching loses: %d" % losses

problem(100)
```

Comment: Try adding print statements in your while loop. Its the only blocking piece of code I see. So if for whatever reason your exit conditions aren't met, it stay in the while loop forever.

Comment: You don't want to use random.choice() for this. For this problem, it's really important to know which doors are selected, not just what is behind the door, so use random.randint(0, 2) or random.randrange(len(doors)) to get the actual door index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the for-loop, but with the while loop.

In order for your while loop to break, `montychoice` would have to equal `car` AND the player's choice. But what if the player's choice isn't `car`, but it's `goat`? The while-loop will never break.

I think you want `and` and not `or` for your while loop. That way, if either condition isn't met, the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this loop

```
while montychoice != 'car' or montychoice == choice:
        montychoice = random.choice(doors)
```

Once the player has picked the car, this says that whether monty picks a car or not a car, he has to pick another choice. So he keeps on picking forever, and you don't get any further in your script.